# regular expression with variable-length zero-width lookbehind in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I understand that Java does not support variable-length zero-width lookbehinds, but is there an efficient and effective way to mimic the desired behaviour?

The text that I'm applying the regex to is something like:

```
blah words blah [tag platform="platform1, platform5" future]Blah Blah blah[/tag] blah more words
```

In the opening tag, there can be any number of platforms in the list, in any order, and there are a finite number of possible values. The desired output is to get the text between the tags:

```
Blah Blah blah
```

This is what I want to do to represent the variable list of platforms:

```
(?<=\\[tag platform=\\\\\".*?\\\\\" future\\]).*?(?=\\[/tag\\])
```

But of course it throws an exception with the message `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`.

I've thought of using a regex to get the entire string including the tags (which is easy), then parse the string. But this seems to be a bit too specific and I'd like a more bulletproof solution.

Comment: Can you add *the expected output* as well?. Side note : For all future regex questions, please add expected output explicitly rather than *stating what is expected* :)

Comment: Why not just use a simpler regex such as (https://regex101.com/r/S1t2qA/1) or something similar and then extract group 2? Java is fully capable of extracting a group out of a match. Perhaps it is preferable to making the regex overly complicated?

Comment: @TheLostMind Thank you for the note, I added the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. No need for a *look-behind*
Just "capture" the necessary part and replace the entire string (or something else)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "blah words blah [tag platform=\"platform1, platform5\" future]Blah Blah blah[/tag] blah more words";
    s = s.replaceAll(".*?\\[tag.*?\\](.*?)(?=\\[.*).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
Blah Blah blah
```

Comment: This will not catch `[` inside the tag and also will match even if the closing tag is not `[/tag]`. https://regex101.com/r/S1t2qA/2

Comment: @jrook - Yes, it doesn't. It can be fixed. Not sure if the OP needs it though.

Comment: @TheLostMind thanks for this, it's very simple and does the job. I actually wasn't aware that you could access each group after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Non-capturing groups to include things in a match, but not a capture
Just remember to pull from the first capture group, instead of the entire match

```
(?:\[tag platform=\".*?\" future\])(.*?)(?:\[\/tag\])
```

[On Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/d9ipfz/2)

Comment: The question states: *there can be any number of platforms in the list* meaning 0 is also possible which will cause this regex to fail

Comment: I Updated the the link, regex still seems to works. Good thought though, I hadn't considered that

Comment: @doom87er Thanks for your response -- I learned about non-capturing groups!